# Is there a way to resolve InvalidArgumentError while using a generator for Neural Networking?

Tags: python-3.x, recurrent-neural-network

I did some modifications and now my error has changed to:
invalidargumenterror:  indices[29,195] = 2036 is not in [0, 2035)

Is there a way to resolve this? Also is there anything wrong on the rest of the program? Thank you.

```
def generator(df,tokenizer,label_encoder, batch_size=32):
                n_examples = len(df)
                number_of_batches = n_examples / batch_size
                counter = 0
                while 1:
                                start_index = index * batch_size
                                end_index = start_index + batch_size
                                if counter > number_of_batches  + 1:
                                               df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
                                               counter = 0
                                counter += 1
                                X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df.iloc[start_index: end_index]['text'])
                                X = sequence.pad_sequences(X, maxlen=160)
                                X = sequence.pad_sequences(X, maxlen=160)
                                Y = label_encoder.transform(df['code'])
                                yield X, Y


# Generators
train_generator = generator(df_train,tokenizer,label_encoder, batch_size=32)
validation_generator = generator(df_valid,tokenizer,label_encoder, batch_size=32)

#import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, GlobalMaxPooling1D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam


input_text = Input(shape=(160,), dtype='int32')
embedding = Embedding(input_dim=len(df_valid) + 1, 
                      output_dim=300, 
                      input_length=160)(input_text)
lstm = LSTM(units=256, 
            dropout=0.5, 
            recurrent_dropout=0.5, 
            return_sequences=True, )(embedding)
pool = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(lstm)
dropout = Dropout(0.5)(pool)
output = Dense(len(label_encoder.classes_), activation='softmax')(dropout)

model = Model(inputs=input_text, outputs=output)
optimer = Adam(lr=.001)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_generator, 
          validation_data=validation_generator,
          epochs=20,steps_per_epoch = len(df_train)/batch_size)
```

Comment: does it give you a line which it is failing at?

Comment: No it does not give me a line.

Comment: it fails and doesn't give a line?! can you please copy the whole exact error(obviously hiding any personal information like your name!!)

Comment: InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[32,545] labels_size=[11416,545]
  [[node loss/dense_8_loss/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (defined at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_27174]

Comment: well i have no idea, sorry,

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate you trying to help.

Comment: I forgot to add the last two lines to the complete error message: Function call stack:
distributed_function

Comment: sorry, still don't know...